# Replace only values of a given list of IDs in large PANEL DATA SET

Tags: r

I'd like to replace only for a list of certain ID's the items of another variable in my data.frame.

Here is what I have:

df1

```
ID | Variable_1
1  | NA
2  | NA
3  | NA
4  | NA
5  | NA
6  | NA
7  | NA
8  | NA
```

df 2

```
ID
1
5
8
```

Now, I would like to replace the items of `Variable_1` in `df1` by the number `11` for all `ID`s listed in `df2` in order to obtain the following output.

df1 (with adjustments)

```
ID | Variable_1
1 | 11
2 | NA
3 | NA
4 | NA
5 | 11
6 | NA
7 | NA
8 | 11
```

Here we had the proposition to deal with the problem by using

> df1$Variable_1[df1$ID %in% df2$ID] <- 11

Howerver, using data.table, with a panel data set of the following form (Note: ID's can have gabs and do not necessarily be ordered, so the %in% component is cruscial) :

> df1 <- data.table( Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001,2002, 2002, 2002, 2002),ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), Variable_1 = rep(NA, 12) )
>
> colnames(df1) = c("Year", "ID", "Variable_1")
>
> df2 <- data.table(Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000), ID = c(1, 2, 4))
>
> colnames(df2) = c("Year", "ID")

The solution below puts TRUE in the corresponding cells instead of the number 11

> df1[Year==2000]$Variable_1[df1[Year==2000]$ID %in% df2$ID] <- 11

Is there any further solution to put directly the wished number ?

Comment: `df1$Variable_1[df2$id] = 11`    ?

Comment: Or `df1$Variable_1[df1$id %in% df2$id] <- 11` if the ids are not ordered or have gaps.

Comment: Obviously there is a problem using $, as r copies the whole table. Modifying the comand in                                                                  df1[Year==2000][,"Variable_1"][df1[Year==2000][,"ID"] %in% df2[,"ID" ] ] = 11                                                                                       does not lead to a result, as there are (wrongly) no matches found. ?

Comment: Ok, got the problem: with an empty column for Variable_1 it works: The following gives the desired output.                                                  df1 <- data.table( Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001,2002, 2002, 2002, 2002),ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), Variable_1 = rep("", 12) )                                                            df1[Year==2000]$Variable_1[df1[Year==2000]$ID %in% df2$ID] <- 11